# combined 4 formulas into 1

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've tried to cobmine to formules but either get Value or Name Error, also, not sure where to search or search for in google.

Any help will be most appreciated.

===========

Column E4 is filled with one of the 4 things.

Low
Medium
High
Urgent

at the moment I have a separate formula for the above

- this will then calculate if it is in SLA

The code I have is

```
=IF(AND(E2="Low",P2<'IC SLA'!$F$6),"IN SLA","OUT SLA")
=IF(AND(E2="Medium",P2<'IC SLA'!$F$5),"IN SLA","OUT SLA")
=IF(AND(E2="High",P2<'IC SLA'!$F$4),"IN SLA","OUT SLA")
=IF(AND(E2="Urgent",P2<'IC SLA'!$F$3),"IN SLA","OUT SLA")
```

P2 = time

IC SLA'!$F$3

IC SLA(sheet)'!$F$3/4/5/6(time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine your four AND within an OR statement. The general pattern would be:

```
=IF(OR(AND1, AND2, AND3, AND4), "IN SLA", "OUT SLA")
```

Using your existing formulas this would be:

```
=IF(OR(AND(E2="Low",P2<'IC SLA'!$F$6), AND(E2="Medium",P2<'IC SLA'!$F$5), AND(E2="High",P2<'IC SLA'!$F$4), AND(E2="Urgent",P2<'IC SLA'!$F$3)), "IN SLA", "OUT SLA")
```

Comment: Thanks dude!, When comparing it with my original combines formula, I didn't include the OR :)